# Migrate DHCP from 2008 to 2012 - Maintain same Hostname and IP

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, migration, dhcp-server

I have two servers, DHCP1 and DHCP2 running on Windows Server 2008 and I want to migrate them both on Windows Server 2012 without downtime to the DHCP service. After reading a few articles this is what I have so far.

1. Export all the DHCP configuration from the 2008 server using "netsh
   dhcp server export C:\Users\user\Desktop\dhcp.txt all"
2. Import all the DHCP configuration on the 2012 server using "netsh
   dhcp server import C:\Users\user\Desktop\dhcp.txt all"
3. Authorize the new DHCP server from the DHCP console.

My problem is that I have to maintain the same hostnames and IP Addresses for the 2012 servers. So I’ll have to bring down one of the 2008 servers, replace it with a 2012 server and import all the configuration I exported from the 2008 server. And then repeat for the second 2008 DHCP server.

1. Will I have to de-authorize the first 2008 server before shutting it
   down and replacing it with a 2012 server?
2. Will the second 2008 server work properly when the first 2008 server
   is replaced with a 2012 server?
3. Anyone who’s done this before, do you have any advice, tips & tricks
   or anything I should be on the lookout for?

I realize this should be a simple task, but I’ve never done it before and I’d like some advice from someone with more experience.

Comment: Are the two existing DHCP Servers configured with different Scopes?

Comment: No, they are configured with the same scopes.

Comment: Are you using the split scope wizard or another method to make sure they don't give out the same IP addresses?

Comment: Why do you need to use the same names and ip addresses for the new servers?

Comment: Have you read the TechNet DHCP Server Migration guide? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495425(v=ws.11).aspx